# How to redirect stdin for bash source command?

Tags: bash

I would like to `source` a file and redirect STDIN for that source. Is it possible?

Example, I have this file I wish to source:

```
# test.sh
export VALUE=SOMETHING
```

This works in a shell:

```
> source test.sh
> echo $VALUE
SOMETHING
>
```

Yet this doesn't work

```
> echo anything | source test.sh
> echo $VALUE

>
```

Is there some way this can be done, or is it because "source" runs in the current shell that it can't possibly redirect STDIN temporarily?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a good reason why this doesn't work:

```
echo anything | source test.sh
```

It is because the above is a pipeline.   Consequently, `source test.sh` runs in a subshell.  That means that any environment variables it creates are discarded when its execution completes.

The solution to your problem is:

```
 source test.sh < <(echo anything)
```

With this approach, `source test.sh` runs in the main shell.  Its stdin is redirected from `echo anything` using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution).

The first `<` redirects stdin.  The second `<` is part of the `<(...)` construct which creates a *[process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution)*.  At least one space between the first and second `<` is required.

Comment: Great. I didn't know about the `<(cmd)` notation in bash.

Comment: Why do I get the feeling <(''<) should also work?

Comment: Can we get a SEARCH HIT for 'Bash; "source" a created script, without use of temporary file' please... (trying to create it here and now!)